# Dealing with titanium Push notifications ios

Tags: javascript, notifications, titanium

Here is my code:

```
Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({  
   types: [  
     Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,  
     Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT  
   ],  
   success:function(e)  
   {  
     var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;  
     Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: "+deviceToken);  
     alert('device token is' +e.deviceToken);  
     Ti.API.info("Push notification types: "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);  
     Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);  
   },  
   error:function(e)  
   {  
     Ti.API.info("Error during registration: "+e.error);  
   },  
   callback:function(e)  
   {  
     // called when a push notification is received.  
    //Titanium.Media.vibrate();  
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);  
    var badge = data.badge;  
    if(badge > 0){  
     Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = badge;  
    }  
    var message = data.message;  
    if(message != ''){  
     var my_alert = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'', message:message});  
     my_alert.show();  
    }  
   }  
  });   
 }
```

The callback function:

```
   callback:function(e)  
   {  
     // called when a push notification is received.  
    //Titanium.Media.vibrate();  
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);  
    var badge = data.badge;  
    if(badge > 0){  
     Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = badge;  
    }  
    var message = data.message;  
    if(message != ''){  
     var my_alert = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'', message:message});  
     my_alert.show();  
    }  
   }  
  });
```

is fired when the push notification is recieved when the app is running in the foreground.

Question , if I have 2 files:

app.js -> newwindow.js

and say that I am in newwindow.js , will I still receive push notifications? (if the code above is all pasted in app.js?)

2) When I recieve a push notification when the app is running in the background, how can I write a callback method for it, so I can tell the app what to do with that notification

3) What is the best way of handling different notifications, i.e. say I need to open different windows, when its in background mode?

```
notification 1 - > win1.js
notification 2 - > win2.js
notification 3 - > win3.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should Implement it in your app(It seems you just copied from docs) and see how actually push notification appear it will make every thing a lot clear.

The callback you have written above will fetch the message that you have send using the Push notification.

As for part 2 of your question : Once the user clicks on the push received your app will come into foreground and the **callback will be automatically called**.

And to handle **different notifications**, there are never different push notifications, there is always a  single push notification.you have to parse the data and have act according to the condition. you can modify your push message and open window according to it.

Comment: Thanks , I have got it working (push notifications) in my app. The second part of your answer, does this mean I have to stick a bunch of if statements in the callback function?

Comment: As a follow up - it seems that this is the way to do it.